# Calculated Column Question - maybe

Tags: lookup-column

I am pretty new to this, so apologies if it is a stupid question.

Basically, I want to know if it is possible to create a column that references another column at the level below.  Specifically, I have a column called 'Status' at file level with the values, 'Initial', 'In Progress' and 'Completed'
I would like to be able to see at the folder level how many of the files are in which status, so I am guessing I need three columns, and then a formula calculating the total of each respective status on the files below.  As I am not sure this is clear, a specific example is I have Folder ABC, that contains 100 excel sheets that need to be completed.  20 have status 'Completed', 20 have status In Progress and 60 have status 'Initial'
It would be great to see from a quick glance at folder level how work is progressing.

Any ideas gratefully received.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you obtain that Status 'Initial' & 'Completed'. In a simple scenario you could create an Extra column on your Document Library that holds that information 
And ensure it is added to the default view. you can then use it as any other column and filter and group by it. This way does rely on your users setting the value in the Column manually, but for a more sophisticated resolution you are looking at workflows. This is a fairly simplistic solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `Event Receivers`.

First you create the needed status columns and attach them to the folder. Then you create an Event Receiver in Visual Studio for the specified list (Where the items and folders will be added). In this Event Receiver you can override the `itemAdding` and the `itemUpdating` events and write code to change the columns values attached to the folder.

If you are new to Event Receivers you can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/gg252010.aspx).